# Gradle multiproject management with mutually exclusive projects

Tags: gradle, multi-project

Consider the following project setup:

```
ProjectRoot
|__build.gradle
|__settings.gradle
|
|__ProjectA
|  |__build.gradle
|
|__ProjectB
|  |__build.gradle
|
|__SharedProject
   |__build.gradle
```

Both projects need `SharedProject` as dependency. However, I only want to build one Project at a time. The current "solution" I have is to simply comment out the project that I am **not** building in `settings.gradle`, e.g.:

```
$ cat settings.gradle
include 'ProjectA'
//include 'ProjectB'
include 'SharedProject'
```

When I call `gradle assembleRelease` ProjectA gets build. In order to build `ProjectB` I comment out `ProjectA` in `settings.gradle`.

I would like to be able to build a specific project without having to comment out the other one in `settings.gradle`, e.g., just issue a command like

```
$ gradle buildA
```

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

`gradle :ProjectA:assembleRelease` will build only ProjectA with its dependencies (including SharedProject).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will it still respect the configuration in ProjectRoot's build.gradle? It has settings in it which apply for all subprojects.